# How did 潛 shift from signifying 'wading in the water' to 'under water'?

Tags: etymology

[CUHK](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%BD%9B) doesn't appear to expound the semantic shift from wading in water to under water.

> 從「[水](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%B0%B4)」，「[朁](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%9C%81)」聲，本義為涉水。《說文》：「涉水也。一曰：藏也。一曰：漢水爲潛。从水，朁聲。」《詩‧小雅‧正月》：「魚在于沼，亦匪克樂；潛雖伏矣，亦孔之炤。」

[image]

Axel Schuessler, *ABC Etymological Dictionary of Old Chinese*  (2007), p 425. But this redirects you to p 303.

[image]

I don[t understand the red underline, which can't refer to dead humans, because dead humans who "lie at bottom of water", aren't normally construed to "be soaked (in pleasure)"...unless you're a sadist! Living humans can't lie at the bottom of water. When humans soak themselves in pleasure, they're usually floating or standing in water.

Comment: Axel Schuessler, ABC Etymological Dictionary? Translation is always difficult in not losing the original meanings. You should check a reputable Chinese dictionary instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My dictionary simply says 潛 - to submerge.

From "萌典"

1. 入水，在水面下活動。如：「潛水」、「鳥飛魚潛」。

- 《左傳·哀公十七年》：「越子以三軍潛涉，當吳中軍而鼓之。」

2. 深藏、隱藏。如：「潛藏」、「潛伏」。

- 唐·杜甫〈奉贈韋左丞丈二十二韻〉：「殘杯與冷炙，到處潛悲辛。」
- 宋·范仲淹〈岳陽樓記〉：「日星隱曜，山岳潛形。」

As I addressed in my comment, the translation you have cited wasn't too good.